# Map $ \mathbb C\setminus\gamma $ conformally to a punctured disk, where $ \gamma = \{ z\in S:Re(z)\le 0 \} $

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $ S $ denote the circle of radius $ \frac{1}{2} $ centered at $ \frac i 2\in\mathbb C $ and let 
>   $$ \gamma = \{ z\in S:Re(z)\le 0 \} $$
>   be the semicircle. 
>   Find a one-to-one and onto holomorphic map from $ \mathbb C\setminus\gamma $ (the complement of $ \gamma $ in $ \mathbb C $ ) to the punctured disk
>   $$ \Delta^*=\{ z\in\mathbb C:0<|z|<1 \}. $$

Can someone give me a hint?

---

**Edit**:

Here is what I have by now:

We start from both $ \mathbb C\setminus\gamma $ and $ \Delta^* $.

On the $ \mathbb C\setminus\gamma $ side, we have:

$$ \begin{align}
&1^\circ\ \text{Translation(Move the center of $ S $ to $ 0 $):}& & z\mapsto z-\frac i 2 \\
&2^\circ\ \text{Rotation(Rotate $ \frac\pi 2 $ clockwise):}& & z\mapsto\exp(-\frac{\pi}{2}i)z \\
&3^\circ\ \text{Linear Fractional Transformation(Map the semicircle to $yi$, $ y
>0 $): }& &z\mapsto\frac{z+1}{z-1}\\
&4^\circ\ \text{Rotation(Rotate $ \frac\pi 2 $ clockwise):}&& z\mapsto\exp(-\frac{\pi}{2}i)z\\
&5^\circ\ \text{Logarithm:}& & z\mapsto \log(z)\\
&6^\circ\ \text{Scale:}& & z\mapsto\frac 1 2 z
\end{align} $$
Through the above process, we get the region $$ \Omega_1:\{ z\in\mathbb C: Im(z)\in (0, \pi ) \} .$$
On the other side, starting from $ \Delta^* $, we have:
\begin{align}
&1^\circ\ \text{Logarithm:}&& z\mapsto\log(z)\\
&2^\circ\ \text{Rotation(Rotate $ \frac\pi 2 $ clockwise):}&& z\mapsto\exp(-\frac{\pi}{2}i)z\\
&3^\circ\ \text{Scale:}& & z\mapsto\frac 1 2 z\\
&4^\circ\ \sin (z):&& z\mapsto \sin(z)\\
&5^\circ\ \text{Logarithm:}&& z\mapsto\log(z)
\end{align}
And we get the region:
$$ \Omega_2:\{z\in\mathbb C: Im(z)\in[0,\pi)\} .$$
But they still vary from the real axis. So how to move on?

Comment: A common trick you've probably encountered is breaking the problem up into pieces. First map your semicircle onto some nice region (for example, a circle) and then keep mapping onto regions that are closer towards your goal. In this case I would probably go semicircle -> circle -> punctured circle but the choice is up to you (for example, a mobius transform will let you work with half planes instead, which can sometimes be easier to move around)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Hello! I have edited my post, but still can't get there. Would you mind posting an answer?

Comment: I'm a bit busy today, but I'll post an answer when I get a chance :)

Comment: While I’m breaking my brain on this, I have two comments. First, rotating ccw by $90^\circ$ is multiplication by $i$, while you seem to have multiplied by $-i$. Second, and much more importantly you have applied the logarithm function to the punctured unit disk, but the log isn’t definable except on *simply connected domains* not containing the origin.

Comment: @Lubin Sorry, it's a typo, I mean clockwise. Why can't we define $ \log (z)=\log|z|+i\arg z $?

Comment: @user549397 shoot, got busy today and forgot to take a look at this. Perhaps tomorrow. To answer your comment, you have to be a bit more careful. Analytic functions are necessarily conformal, but the logarithm will not be analytic on the punctured unit disk. It is analytic only on simply connected regions not containing the branch point at the origin. It may not be conformal on the region you want it to be

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks for your reply! But still, I am confused about why the logarithm is not conformal on the punctured disk?

Comment: @user549397 the problem is that an annulus winds around the origin, so somewhere your logarithm has to jump by $2\pi i$... It has to have a branch cut *somewhere* coming out from the origin, and since the punctured disks wraps completely around the origin the branch cut must intersect the punctured disk. As such, our logarithm is not analytic on the region so there is no reason to suppose it will be conformal (the only reason we usually have the logarithm being conformal is that it is analytic - recall all analytic maps are conformal)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I See, Thank you~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a Mobius transformation $\mu$ that maps $\gamma$ to $[-1, 1]$. It maps $\mathbb C \setminus \gamma$ to $\overline {\mathbb C} \setminus ([-1, 1] \cup \{\mu(\infty)\})$. Take the branch $J^{-1}$ of the inverse Joukowsky transformation that maps $\overline {\mathbb C} \setminus [-1, 1]$ to the open unit disk $\mathbb D$. The composition $J^{-1} \circ \mu$ maps $\mathbb C\setminus \gamma$ to $\mathbb D \setminus \{J^{-1}(\mu(\infty))\}$. Then take a Mobius transformation that maps $\mathbb D$ to itself and maps $J^{-1}(\mu(\infty))$ to $0$.

Comment: This is it. I totally misread the request, so my answer should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

This is a detailed version of @Maxim's:

$ 1^\circ $ Take a Mobius transformation $ \mu $ that maps $ \gamma $ to $ [-1,1] $: Let's find such a Mobius transformation, such that 
\begin{align} &z_1=&i&\mapsto 1&=\omega_1\\
&z_2=&-\frac 1 2+\frac 1 2i&\mapsto 0&=\omega_2\\
&z_3=&0&\mapsto -1&=\omega_3
\end{align}
Since Mobius transformation preserves the corss-ratio, we have:
\begin{align}
\frac{\omega-\omega_1}{\omega-\omega_2}:\frac{\omega_3-\omega_1}{\omega_3-\omega_2}&=\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}:\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_3-z_2}\\
\frac{\omega-1}{\omega}\cdot\frac{-1}{-1-1}&=\frac{z-i}{z+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\frac 1 2 i}{-i}\\
1-\frac 1 \omega&=\frac{2z-2i}{2z+1-i}\cdot(1+i)\\
\omega&=\frac{2z+1-i}{-2iz-1+i}
\end{align}
Note that $$ \mu(\infty)=i .$$

$2^\circ$ Take the branch of inverse Joukowsky transformation:

$$ J^{-1}(z)=z-\sqrt{z^2-1} $$ 
mapping $ \overline{\mathbb C}\setminus [-1,1] $ to the unit open disk $ \mathbb D .$

Note that $$ J^{-1}(\mu(\infty))=(1-\sqrt{2})i .$$

$ 3^\circ $ Take a Mobius transformation that maps $ \mathbb D $ to itself and maps $ \mu(\infty)=i $ to $ 0 $. It is of the form:
$$ z\mapsto \omega=e^{i\theta}\frac{z-(1-\sqrt{2})i}{1-z\overline{(1-\sqrt{2})i}} $$ 
Take $ \theta=0 $ and we get
$$ z\mapsto \omega=\frac{z-(1-\sqrt 2)i}{1-z(\sqrt 2-1)i} $$

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: the answer below is wrong, as a result of my misunderstanding of what the original region was.

---

I feel kind of stupid for not seeing how to do this sooner. A good sleep helped, I guess.

The circular disk whose right half you want to exclude is tangent to the real axis at the origin, and its maximum point is $i$. Let’s call the circle itself (not the disk) $C$, the right semicircle $C_R$, the left $C_L$. The vertical diameter, running from the origin to $i$ I’ll call $D$.

Use the map $z\mapsto1/z$ and see what happens. $C_R$ gets sent to the horizontal ray going rightwards from $-i$ and $D$ goes to the vertical ray going downwards from $-i$. ($C_L$, which is in the midst of the region of our interest, goes to the horizontal ray that runs leftward from $-i$.)

Thus the bad region, the righthand interior of the circular disk, goes to the right-angled wedge going SE from the point $-i$, while the good region is everything else, that is, $\{z:\Re(z)<0\}\cup\{z:\Im(z)>-1\}$.

From here on, it’s clear what you need to do: move up by one unit, $z\mapsto z+i$ to get your wedges with their vertex at the origin, and then apply the conformal map $z\mapsto z^{2/3}$, which has the effect of straightening out the $270^\circ$ angle to $180^\circ$. Now the good region is a half-plane, in fact the upper half-plane. Note that $\infty$, which is, so to speak, the isolated point in the exterior of our original good region, has gone first to $0$, the to $i$, and to $\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\,$. I’m going to call this number $\zeta$: it’s a primitive sixth root of unity.

Finally, map the upper half-plane to the interior of the unit circle by
$$
z\mapsto\frac{z-\zeta}{z-\bar\zeta}\,,
$$
in which you see that real numbers get sent to the unit circle, while $\zeta$ gets sent to the origin. Compose all the steps in the right order, see that $i\mapsto-i\mapsto0\mapsto0\mapsto-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2$; $\infty\mapsto0\mapsto i\mapsto\zeta\mapsto0$; $\frac i2\mapsto-2i\mapsto-i\mapsto\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac i2\mapsto\zeta$; and $0\mapsto\infty\mapsto\infty\mapsto\infty\mapsto1$.

And there you are.

Comment: I think the question is about the plane minus the left semicircle, not minus the right half-disk.

Comment: @Maxim, of course you’re right. I’m in a quandary now as to whether to delete the answer.