# Conformal Mappings and Mapping the Complement of an Arc

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I'm working on a question from Ahlfors' $\textit{Complex Analysis}.$ The question reads:

> Map the complement of the arc $|z| = 1, y \geq 0$ on the outside of the unit circle so that the points at $\infty$ correspond to each other.

I have multiple questions with this, but the foremost of these is that I'm not even sure I understand what region I'm mapping into. Is it the entire complement of the unit circle? And from there, I'm not sure I'd know where to go. I know how to map the region into the half plane (if I'm picturing the correct region), but I'm not even sure that is the right direction.

Any clarification would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this supposed to be $|z|=1$ instead of $|z|<1$? Otherwise this is not an arc, and not closed either.

Comment: @LukasGeyer Yes, that is correct. Thanks for noticing; it has been corrected.

Comment: The "unit circle" is $\{z \in \mathbb C \mid |z|=1\}$, and the "outside of the unit circle" is $\{z \in \mathbb C \mid |z|>1\}$.

Comment: Hint: It might be easier to think of the inverse map. If $f$ maps the outside of the unit disk to the complement of the circular arc, you can extend it by reflection in the unit circle to a rational map of degree $2$. Then automatically $f(0)=0$, and if you assume symmetry with respect to the imaginary axis you would get another zero somewhere on the imaginary axis. Poles would be at $\infty$ and at the reflected image of the other zero. From this information you can construct the function explicitly without much trouble.

Comment: The image is $\{ z: |z| > 1 \}$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3167972).